# Autocomplete using JSON value in variable for source?

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-ui, object, autocomplete

`jQuerys .autocomplete()` function has two variants for it's 'source' option.

An Array of Strings:

```
[ "Choice1", "Choice2" ]
```

An Array of Objects with label and value properties:

```
 [ { label: "Choice1", value: "value1" }, ... ]
```

These both work fine when passed directly to the `.autocomplete()` function:

```
$('input').autocomplete({source: [ "Choice1", "Choice2" ], minLength: 0});
```

OR

```
$('input').autocomplete({source: [ { label: "Choice1", value: "value1" } ], minLength: 0});
```

BUT I can't get either to work when passed as variables:

```
var source = '[ "Choice1", "Choice2" ]';
$('input').autocomplete({source: source, minLength: 0});
```

This is to do with implicit casting of the variable to a string - autocomplete treats the values from the variable identically to how it handles an `AJAX source` (which is a string).

Ultimately I want to use a `JSON` value from a `data-json` attribute of the input element.

For added interest:

```
$('input').autocomplete({source: $('input').data('json'), minLength: 0});
```

works perfectly for the first variant, but reverts to the string behavior for the second variant.

Using `$('input').attr('data-json')` doesn't work for either variant.

A 'hack' which does work for both variants is to do this:

```
$('input').autocomplete({source: eval($('input').attr('data-json')), minLength: 0});
```

Did I miss something which would allow `.data()` to return the apparently valid `JSON` in the second variant as an object?

Is there another way, or do I just need to make peace with `eval()` despite all the wisdom around that it's probably not a good thing to do?

Thanks for your thoughts..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var source = '[ "Choice1", "Choice2" ]';
```

That is a *String*, not an array.

Try without quotes:

```
var source = [ "Choice1", "Choice2" ];
```

If you find yourself in the situation of having to get the data from a JSON string, don't use eval (it's evil), use JSON.parse (which all modern browsers have)

```
var source = JSON.parse( '[ "Choice1", "Choice2" ]' );
```

or, since you are already using jQuery

```
var source = $.parseJSON( '[ "Choice1", "Choice2" ]' );
```

Comment: jQuery has its own method for parsing json, called `$.parseJSON(json);` http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/ . using `JSON.parse` might give problems with browser compatibility however jQuery will support most of the IEs aswell as the hip modern crowd.

Comment: Thanks Thilo - I still think .data() should be consistent.
I used strings in the var source as they were standing in for the $('input').attr('data-json') value - which returns a string.

Comment: I'm still stuck - $.parseJSON('[ { label: "Choice1", value: "value1" }, { label: "Choice2", value: "value2" } ]') fails silently - try calling that from inside an alert(). eval() works though. Any further thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

An underlying issue here was that the "JSON" accepted by the autocomplete plugin, and detailed in the [documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/):

```
[ { label: "Choice1", value: "value1" }, ... ]
```

Is not actually valid JSON. JSONLint.com made this apparent.

I had exactly duplicated the example format in my string, but while autocomplete will accept that syntax directly, it can't be converted to a js Object except through the use of eval().

The answer is that we need to quote the property names as well as the values. A valid notation is:

```
[ { "label": "Choice1", "value": "value1" }, { "label": "Choice2", "value": "value2" },...]
```

Hope that helps someone out!